# BroadcastReceiever on separate process

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver which is working, but when I go into recent and swipe the app to get rid of it, the receiver stops working.

So i wanted to add this to the manifest i nhopes to prevent the receiver from dying

```
<receiver
    android:name=".CounterReceiver"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:process=":counterreceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.johnbravado.zionwork.MESSAGE_PROCESSED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Send the receiver to a different process. Now, however, my receiver does not work at all. If I remove the `android:process=""` line, it goes back to working as expected.

Is this normal behavior or do i need to sendBroadcasta special way for the receiver to hear it since it is ona separate process?

Edit:

Here is the sending system. the sender is coming from a service

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    nodeId = messageEvent.getSourceNodeId();
    String incomingPath = messageEvent.getPath();
    int incomingReq = Integer.parseInt(new String(messageEvent.getData()));

    if(incomingPath.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.MSG_COUNTER_REQ_PATH)) {

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(MyConstants.BROADCAST_ACTION_RESP);
        //broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, incomingReq);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }else if(incomingPath.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.MSG_DEFAULT_PATH)){

    }
}
```

The sending service manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".MyWearableListenerService"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:scheme="wear" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I know i have enabled=false that is not issue as i set it to true via package manager.

Comment: can you paste the code for the part when you send the intent?

Comment: do yo want it to be disabled? (android:enabled="false")

Comment: see updated OP. and i enable the receiver via packagemanager as needed.

Comment: "when I go into recent and swipe the app to get rid of it, the receiver stops working" -- on most devices, that would occur if the process were terminated and you had registered the receiver via `registerReceiver()`. On a few devices, they tied their app manager to the Force Stop behavior. In that case, nothing will cause your code to run again until the user launches your app from the home screen launcher or something else uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. Devices that Force Stop apps this way are evil, but there is nothing that you can do about them.

Comment: I do not register/unregisterReceiver. instead I use ComponentName and PackageManager to update the enable=true and enable = false as needed to turn it on and off

Comment: How do you know that "receiver does not work at all" when it runs in a child process?

Comment: I believe the receiver is operating, but it cannot "hear" the broadcast from a different process.

Comment: did you try, for testing, to remove `android:enabled="false"` ?

Comment: yes that is not the culprit

Comment: @JohnBravado any success? How were you able to get broadcast which was fired from another process?

Comment: I was unable to find a proper way so I just used creation of file while the other process would periodically check for that file. It's a poor solution but I have wasted 3 days on this already. Binding to service for Message didn't work either. I may have looked into AIDL if I had more time to investigate it.